# TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Equal' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm pretty new to Keras and LSTMs. I've been trying to train my model of sequences to predict the future price of a stock with the code below but the error above kept popping up.

I have tried changing the dtypes of both x_data, y_data with .astype(np.float16). However, all times I am returned with the TypeError stating that I have a float32 type.

If it helps, here are the shapes of my data:

> xtrain.shape : (32, 24, 67),  ytrain.shape : (32, 24, 1),  xtest.shape
>   : (38, 67),  ytest.shape : (38, 1)

Does anyone have any idea on what might be wrong? I've been stuck at this for awhile. It would be great if someone could give me a hint.

```
y_data = y_data.to_numpy().astype(np.float32)
x_data = main_df.to_numpy().astype(np.float32)

num_x_signals = x_data.shape[1]
num_y_signals = y_data.shape[1]

# SPLIT TRAIN TEST DATA
ratio = 0.85
train_ratio = int(ratio * len(x_data))

x_train = x_data[0:train_ratio]
x_test = x_data[train_ratio:]

y_train = y_data[0:train_ratio]
y_test = y_data[train_ratio:]

# GENERATE RANDOM SEQUENCES
batch_size = 32
sequence_length = 24
EPOCHS = 50

def batch_generator(x_train, y_train, batch_size, sequence_length, num_x_signals, num_y_signals, num_train):
    while True:
        x_shape = (batch_size, sequence_length, num_x_signals)
        x_batch = np.zeros(shape = x_shape).astype(np.float32)

        y_shape = (batch_size, sequence_length, num_y_signals)
        y_batch = np.zeros(shape = y_shape).astype(np.float32)

        for i in range(batch_size):
            idx = np.random.randint(num_train - sequence_length)

            x_batch[i] = x_train[idx:idx+sequence_length]
            y_batch[i] = y_train[idx:idx+sequence_length]

        yield (x_batch, y_batch)

generator = batch_generator(x_train, y_train, batch_size, sequence_length, num_x_signals, num_y_signals, train_ratio)
xtrain, ytrain = next(generator)
xtest, ytest = (np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=0),
                np.expand_dims(y_test, axis=0))

# LSTM MODEL
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape = (None, num_x_signals,), return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.18))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001, decay = 1e-6)

model.compile(
    loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer = opt,
    metrics = ['accuracy']
)

name_of_file = f"{to_predict}-{sequence_length}-{future_predict}-{int(time.time())}"
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir = "logs/{}".format(name_of_file))

filepath = "LSTM_Final-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.3f}"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("models/{}.model".format(filepath, monitor = 'val_acc', verbose = 1, save_best_only = True, mode = 'max')) # saves only the best ones

history = model.fit(
    xtrain, ytrain,
    epochs = EPOCHS,
    validation_data = (xtest, ytest),
    callbacks = [tensorboard, checkpoint]
)

score = model.evaluate(xtest, ytest, verbose = 0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

model.save("models/{}".format(name_of_file))
```

Comment: Hi,
Can you add error log here?

Comment: Hey! I appreciate the reply! :) I managed to solve it after digging harder. Turns out, I needed to add "steps_per_epoch" field under model.fit().

Comment: It would be great if you could share your solution (with code examples) as the as an answer.

Comment: I'm doing this: self.model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, steps_per_epoch=1) and still getting an error.

Answer (score 2):

I found this issue had to do with the loss function specified.

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=[3]),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

#I changed the loss function from 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' to 'mean_squared error'
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])

X = train_dataset.to_numpy()
y = train_labels.to_numpy()
model.fit(X,y, epochs=5)
```

X shape was (920,3) and dtype = float64

y shape was (920,1) and dtype = float64

My problem was in the model.fit method. I took the 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' function from an image recognition example and what I was trying here is a neural network for house prices prediction.